# Entity Framework Code First Table Structure for Sales Commissions

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, database-schema

I'm working on a commission caculator where for a given ProjectID multiple salespeople can share commission on that project. So for project A Salesperson 01 and 02 can split the commission 60/40. For project B Salesperson 03 can earn 100% commission. I'm trying to find the best schema to support this and have tried both many to many and one to many. What is best practice?

**Solution #1: using 3 tables**

```
dbo.Salesperson
-SalespersonId

dbo.CommissionSplits
-ProjectId
-CommissionRate

dbo.SalesPersonCommissionSplits
-Salesperson_Id
-CommissionSplits_Id
```

**Solution #2: using 2 tables**

```
dbo.Salesperson
-SalespersonId

dbo.CommissionSplits
-ProjectId
-SalespersonId FK to Salesperson table
-CommissionRate
```

Comment: Assuming you have a Project entity, a SalesPerson entity then IMO you should have a ProjectSalesPerson entity where SalesPeople are assigned to Projects and commission rate is a property in that table. Down the line you might be asked to make one salesperson the lead so you can just add that field to the table. etc.

Comment: Besides the name being different, wouldn't that essentially be what I have with CommissionSplits entity? It would be ProjectID, SalespersonID, and CommissionRate

Comment: Yes, but you asked for best practices. The default EF name would be ProjectSalesPerson. There are cases where it makes sense to override this. For example joining invoices and products might be called LineItems, but I wouldn't call it InvoiceQuantity or InvoiceCost.

Comment: Makes sense. By "default" EF name, where would this default name be generated? I'm using Code First so all entities/classes are named by the developer correct? The only time I've seen migrations auto generate a table and name is when building a many-to-many relationship and EF migrations would generate a Bridge table for the relationship.

Comment: Yes, it will autogenerate the bridge table name unless you create a model or name it in the fluent api.